# Does VS Code's markdown support double bracket links?

Tags: markdown, visual-studio-code

It doesn't seem like the Markdown previer of VS Code supports `[[Double Bracket Links]]`, which ideally would open up the `Double  Bracket Links.md` file. Is this due to a missing setting or similar?

Can I get these links to work within VS Code, via an extension or similar?

Optionally, it would be great if it supports stuff like `[[My long filname|shortened]]` which would link to `My long filename.md`, but display the `shortened` text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that VS Code can use an extension I used in Atom, namely [Markdown Preview Enhanced](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shd101wyy.markdown-preview-enhanced). This can be installed directly within VS Code using the Extension activity and searching for "Markdown Preview Enhanced", and to get the double bracket link go into *Settings > Extensions > Markdown Preview Enhanced*, and locate the *Enable Wiki Link Syntax* and make sure this is enabled.